# How do i copy columns from one file into another?

Tags: excel, vba

i need your help. I have two excel files and i want to do a few things with it. At first i want to copy specific columns from sheet1 in the original file to sheet2 within the orginal file. I accomplished that. But now i also want to copy three specific columns from another workbook(excel file) to sheet2 within the original file. Below you can see my code. The second part of the code (begins with set OpenWb..) doesnt work. Any idea why it doesnt work or any idea for a different approach is much appreciated.

```
Sub Makro2()
    Range("E2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-183
    Range("H2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Tabelle2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
 
    Set OpenWb = Workbooks.Open("......xlsx")
    LastRowCW = OpenWb.Sheets(1).Range("CW99999").End(xlUp).Row
    OpenWb.Sheets(1).Range("CW2: CW" & LastRowCW).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("F1")
    LastRowCT = OpenWb.Sheets(1).Range("CT99999").End(xlUp).Row
    OpenWb.Sheets(1).Range("CT2: CT" & LastRowCT).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("G1")
    LastRowCN = OpenWb.Sheets(1).Range("CN99999").End(xlUp).Row
    OpenWb.Sheets(1).Range("CN2: CN" & LastRowCN).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("I1")
 
 
    Worksheets(2).Activate
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("G1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(12, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. *The second part doesnt work* is unclear. Please, be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly, you're trying to Open another Excel file, selecting and copying columns from that file to your original "Sheet2"

With the code below you can open a file, activate that window, copy data and then paste it in "sheet2"

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Documents\Rest.xlsx"
Windows("Rest.xlsx").Activate
Range("A:C").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Schwebe.xlsx").Activate
Range("F1").PasteSpecial
```

I'd advise to start copying just 1 cell from that new file range before anything!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank  you for your help. Sadly it didnt work for me. I want to achieve the following (more detailed).  1) We have to files. The first one is called Schwebe.xlsm and the second one Rest.xlsm. In the first step i want to copy three columns from Schwebe.xlsm into a new created woorksheet within the file. 2) Here comes Rest.xlsm into play. I want the code to open Rest.xlsm, then copy column A and paste into column F of worksheet2 of Schwebe.xlsm. I want to repeat this process for column B and C from Rest.xls. I hope this helps you more.

Comment: did some tweaks to help you

Comment: Thank you, it worked. One more question, if I want to copy the columns individually bsp from A2 to the end of column A, how do I have to adjust the following line?
Range("CN2:CN").Select

Comment: I always use this line to search for the LAST ROW `lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row` and after that line you can do `Range("CN2:CN" & lr).Select`

Comment: Thanks. Do you also have an idea on how to change/get rid of this line "Windows("Rest.xlsx").Activate". Since this files name changes every day, it would be a pain in the *** to manually change it every day. Is it possible to change this line so that it automatically recognizes that it is in the first file opened?